# How do I write the gradient in angular coordinates ($\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, differentiation, calculus

I have to find $\tau$ by finding the gradient of $U(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3)$, where my coordinates are $(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3)$. I assume the gradient is not the simple Cartesian coordinates formula. However, using the spherical or cylindrical coordinates formula seems wrong since my coordinates are three angles and not an angle and a radius. So how do I express $\nabla U$ in this $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$, $\theta_3$ coordinate system? Is there a Jacobian I need, or some other way?

Edit - To make this question clearer, is there a way to express the $\nabla$ operator in a roll-pitch-yaw $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ coordinate space? Analogous to how in Cartesian coordinates $\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} e_x + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} e_y + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} e_z$. I know that the general way to do something like this is via the Jacobian matrix arising from the metric, but am unsure how to do it in this three angle space.

Comment: There's not enough information as to what you want in the question. What is $\tau$ for example?

Comment: You cannot coordinatize a three dimensional vector space like $\mathbb{R}^3$ via three angles (unless there is some auxiliary information you haven't provided, like angles *of what...*). You need some units of length somewhere and angles are dimensionless. Please clarify what do the three angles represent, then perhaps someone can help you

Comment: @Amit These are angles of rotation in 3D, so roll, pitch and yaw. I was thinking of my 3D space being in terms of these angles, because the torque $\tau$ is $\frac{dU}{d\theta}$ in 1D, so I extended this to 3D.

Comment: @mikestone $\tau$ is the torque on an object that causes it to roll, pitch and yaw in 3D.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense, since it seems clear to me that there isn't a unique torque that can generate a specific rotation. And if you're looking for just any torque, that's a different matter. Maybe I'm wrong about this...

Comment: If you want the orientation of an object you should use Euler angles, but I suspect that if you want the dynamic  of an object such as a plane you need the Euler equations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)

Comment: Just to explain why I'm saying this: you can apply a force with a long radius and arrange the torque to be equal (as a vector) to a stronger force with a shorter radius.

Comment: @mikestone Thank you for the reference. I am more so just looking for a way to represent $\nabla$ in these angular coordinates, and was stuck because the usual way of using the Jacobian, e.g., going from Cartesian to spherical, was not working for me.

Comment: The problem is that those are not coordinates, so I don't think you can find what you're looking for

Comment: Torque is a vector, a vector has *components*. Coordinates also have components, but those components *map physical space*. (Apart from some abstract cases like phase space, I assume you aren't talking of something like that). Now, a position vector for example happens to have components that correspond to coordinates. Not all vectors are like that!

Comment: @Amit That is what I am starting to think. Is there a way to shift $xyz$ to these angles? I am stuck because usually this kind of problem is shifting to something like $r \theta \phi$ where there are defined transformation equations, but here I need to somehow represent $xyz$ in these three $\theta$.

Comment: BTW when you mentioned $U$ I assume that's the potential energy. Are you saying you are given the potential energy as a function of three angles? That's weird....

Comment: Check if this helps you: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/428409/ 
It seems like you can derive the potential energy w.r.t each of angles, then reconstruct the torque as a vector by multiplying via $\hat{n}$ of each appropriate axis.

Comment: @Amit Yes, like $U = \frac{1}{2} k_1 \theta_1^2$, which would be potential energy for a torque spring.

Comment: @StackExchanger I've added an answer. If it is correct, it turns out to be very similar to the regular cartesian gradient, but with the crucial difference that the axis are the rotation axis. So I don't think anyone would define that as a gradient :)

Comment: Really, the coordinates you're talking about are not coordinates on the space of positions (i.e., $\mathbb{R}^3$) but on the space of orientations (i.e., $SO(3)$.)  $SO(3)$ does have a manifold structure, so you could define a gradient operator on it.  But I'm not sure if this gradient operator would have the meaning you want it to;  in particular, the gradient of a scalar like $U$ wouldn't yield a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but instead a one-form on $SO(3)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

**$~\vec \nabla~$ Operator and Jacobian -Matrix**

\begin{align*}
&\text{Nabla Operator sphere  coordinate is }\\\\
&\vec{\nabla}=\vec{e}_r\,\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r} \,  
\vec{e}_\theta\,\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}+ \frac{1}{r\,\sin(\theta)}\,  
\vec{e}_\phi\,\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}  
  \end{align*}

with the sphere position vector $~\vec P~$
\begin{align*}
    &\vec{P}=\left[ \begin {array}{c} r\cos \left( \phi \right) \sin \left( \theta
 \right) \\  r\sin \left( \phi \right) \sin \left(
\theta \right) \\  r\cos \left( \theta \right)
\end {array} \right]\quad,
\vec e_r=\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial r}\quad,
\frac{1}{r}\,\vec{e}_\theta=\frac{\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial \theta}}{|\frac{\partial\vec P}{\partial \theta}|}=\hat{\b{e}}_\theta\quad,
\frac{1}{r\,\sin(\theta)}\,
\vec{e}_\phi=\hat{\b{e}}_\phi\quad\Rightarrow\\
  \end{align*}
\begin{align*}
    &\vec{\nabla}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
                    \hat{\b{e}}_r & \hat{\b{e}}_\theta & \hat{\b{e}}_\phi \\
                  \end{bmatrix}}_{\hat{\b{J}}_(\,3\times 3)}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \\\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \\\\
  \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \\\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad ,\b J_{i,j}=\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial \b q_j}\quad,
\b q=\begin{bmatrix}
       r & \theta & \phi \\
     \end{bmatrix}^T
  \end{align*}
where $~\b J~$ is the Jacobian-Matrix , and "hat" is the matrix column  norm

**your case**

\begin{align*}
    &\vec{P}=\b R_z(\psi)\,\b R_y(\theta)\,\b R_y(\phi)\,
    \begin{bmatrix}
      u_x \\
      u_y \\
      u_z \\
    \end{bmatrix}\quad,
    \b q=\begin{bmatrix}
      \psi \\
      \theta \\
      \phi \\
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align*}

---

the torque is:

$$\b\tau=\b r\times\b F=
-\b r\times\,\hat{\b{J}}\,\begin{bmatrix}
      \frac{\partial U}{\partial\psi} \\
     \frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta} \\
      \frac{\partial U}{\partial\phi} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks! So in this case, $\nabla$ is the Jacobian times a row vector of the $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ (or $\psi, \theta, \phi$), with the Jacobian being the matrix that transforms $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3$ to $x, y, z$?

Comment: The Jacobian Matrix is $~J_{i,j}=\frac{\partial P_i}{\partial \b q_j}~$ partial derivative of the position vector to the generalized coordinates. Try to obtain the Nabla vector for the sphere with this concept !

I did_'t used $~\theta_i~$ instead I used $~\psi~,\theta~,\phi~$ yaw pitch ans roll angle

Comment: Thanks. Using this concept,to go from $(\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3)$ to $(x, y)$, I got the Jacobian $J = (\sum_i \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial \theta_i^2} \sum_i \frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial \theta_i^2})^{T}$. The follow up question I had from this is how to express $x$ and $y$ in terms of these three angles (spherical coordinates just has two). The physical problem I am working with is planar, so there is no $z$ axis, but still these three angles (all three are not fully independent of each other).

Answer (score 0):

Based on: [Is torque always equal to the derivative of potential energy with respect to rotation angle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/428409/is-torque-always-equal-to-the-derivative-of-potential-energy-with-respect-to-rot)

Since we have:
$$ \hat{n}_{\theta_i}\cdot\vec{\tau} = -\frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta_i}$$

For $i=1,2,3$ , then you may reconstruct the Torque vector via:

$$ \vec{\tau} = -\sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{\partial U}{\partial\theta_i}  \hat{n}_{\theta_i} $$

This is not the gradient, at least not in the usual sense of the word, although it has a very similar form. Most importantly: the angles $\theta_i$ may represent rotations from "shifted" axes, in particular this is true for [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). So it's important to know whether the angles refer to an intrinsic or an extrinsic frame, in order to appropriately determine the $\hat{n}_{\theta_i}$'s.

See [this](https://www.lehman.edu/faculty/dgaranin/Mechanics/Mechanis_of_rigid_bodies.pdf) for a lot more related information about rotation mechanics of rigid bodies.

Comment: Thanks! So in this case, the $n_{\theta}$ is some unit vector in the direction of that $\theta$. For the purpose of defining a gradient with unit vectors $n_{\theta_1}$, $n_{\theta_2} and $n_{\theta_3}$, is there a specific way to go about it? I am not sure how to construct a Jacobian moving from Cartesian unit vectors to these three unit vectors.

Comment: the $\hat{n}_{\theta_i}$ are unit vectors along the axis of rotation (direction of course determined by right hand rule...).

Comment: Please see also the linked answer. I notice now there is a way to define this with a direct application of the gradient operator, which is used there.

Comment: $\theta$ being an angle has no defined direction in and of itself, I hope that's clear. You need to know which axis each angle refers to, and I suppose that's given in the problem.

Comment: If it happens that the angles are ordered from 1 to 3 as rotations about the x,y,z axis then what I wrote above coincides with $-\nabla U$ w.r.t the angles, but in general *it will not*

Comment: Thanks! The angles are defined as rotations about specific linear axes, so this should work.

Comment: @StackExchanger if all angles are with respect to the *fixed* orthogonal axes x,y,z then it should be ok. Note that for example for Euler angles this is not the case: the axes get "dragged" along with each successive rotation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help - this gives me a lot to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Using roll, pitch, and yaw is overspecified, and does not tell you the distance.  For example, telling a bomber jet where to fire, you could specify pitch angle and yaw angle, but roll angle does not add anything. The third thing you need is distance downrange.

Also, force is the (negative) derivative of potential energy of a system with respect to some degree of freedom $q$:

$$F=-\frac {dU}{dq}$$

it only becomes a 3D gradient when the potential energy is a field extending over 3D space (like a gravitational or electric field).  In the case of a displaced spring the degree of freedom $q$ might be spring displacement $\Delta x$ or for a pendulum might be angle from vertical $\theta$.